# How to add condition for showing div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I tried adding  condition in Javascript for div show:hide in HTML5

```
#demo {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none; 
}
```

Insert value between 0-9 to set function

```
<input id="num" type="text" name="txt1">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button> 
<div id="demo">This is my Demo element.</div>
<div id="qwe"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var num;
  num = document.getElementById("num").value;
   if (a < 10) {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "inline"; }
    else { document.getElementById("qwe").innerHTML = "Not a Valid Number"; 
   }
}
</script>
```

Am I wrong in the condition part

Comment: you have used 'a' variable in if which is not declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used undefined variable "a"

```
if (a < 10) {
```

you have to change it to:

```
if (num < 10) {
```

try this code:

```html
<input id="num" type="text" name="txt1">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button> 
<div id="demo">This is my Demo element.</div>
<div id="qwe"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var num;
   num = document.getElementById("num").value;
   if (num < 10) {
       document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "inline"; 
       document.getElementById("qwe").innerHTML = "";
   } else { 
       document.getElementById("qwe").innerHTML = "Not a Valid Number";
       document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none"; 
   }
}
</script>
```